Various errors of can't have a value of 'null'
I am reading Flutter Cookbook - Second Edition by Simone Alessandria and got errors in Chapter 4 in the star.dart file:
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/star.dart:8:9: Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 - 'Key' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart' ('../../../../SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/key.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
    Key key,
        ^^^
lib/star.dart:9:10: Error: The parameter 'color' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Color', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
    this.color,
         ^^^^^
lib/star.dart:10:10: Error: The parameter 'size' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'double', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
    this.size,
         ^^^^
lib/star.dart:65:9: Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 - 'Key' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart' ('../../../../SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/key.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
    Key key,
        ^^^
lib/star.dart:66:20: Error: The parameter 'value' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'int', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
    @required this.value,
                   ^^^^^
Failed to compile application.


Exited (1).

Here is the star.dart file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Star extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final double size;

  const Star({
    Key key,
    this.color,
    this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: _StarPainter(color),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _StarPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  _StarPainter(this.color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = color;

    final path = Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.5, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.618, size.height * 0.382);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.382);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.691, size.height * 0.618);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.809, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.7639);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.191, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.309, size.height * 0.618);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.309, size.height * 0.618);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.382);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.382, size.height * 0.382);

    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class StarRating extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final int value;
  final double starSize;

  const StarRating({
    Key key,
    @required this.value,
    this.color = Colors.deepOrange,
    this.starSize = 25,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: List.generate(
        value,
        (_) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Star(
            color: color,
            size: starSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The full code can be found on the author's GitHub

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters . Also, if you are following the second edition of the book, you should use the second edition example repository since I can see the one you linked to have not been updated to null-safety: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Flutter-Cookbook-Second-Edition

Change
const StarRating({
    Key key,
    @required this.value,
    this.color = Colors.deepOrange,
    this.starSize = 25,
  }) : super(key: key);

to
  const StarRating({
    Key? key,
    @required this.value,
    this.color = Colors.deepOrange,
    this.starSize = 25,
  }) : super(key: key);

Key should be optional

The book was outdated and contain an older example when null safety was not introduced to flutter(prior to version 2.12) and you might be using the latest version of flutter sdk(You can check by running flutter --version command on terminal) So I would suggest you to read more recent content to learn flutter
